# What will be $\mathcal {I} (V)$ if $V = \varnothing$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $L$ be a field and $K$ be a subfield of $L.$ Let $V$ be an affine algebraic $K$-variety in $\Bbb A^n (L).$ Consider the vanishing ideal  of $V$

$$\begin{align} \mathcal {I} (V) & = \left \{f \in K[X_2,X_2, \cdots , X_n] : f(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) = 0\ \text {for all}\ (x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in V \right \}. \end{align}$$

Now let us suppose that $V = \varnothing.$ Then what can we say about $\mathcal {I} (V)$? Is it the whole of $K[X_1,X_2, \cdots ,X_n]$ or some other else?

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: If $f \not\in I(V)$, then there exists $x \in V$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$, a contradiction.

Comment: So you mean that $\mathcal {I} (V) = K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n].$ Have I rightly understood your comment above @leibnewtz?

Comment: That's right. We know $I(V) \subseteq K[X]$, so assume there exists $f \in K[X]$ such that $f \not\in I(V)$.

Comment: By ur definition $\mathcal I(\phi) = \{f \in K[X_1,..,X_n] : f(p)=0 \forall p \in \phi \}= K[X_1,...,X_n]$ since the condition is vacuously true

Comment: ধন্যবাদ সৌমিক ঘোষ।